# How to check if there was conflict in SQLite db Android upon inserting?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to check if there was conflict in SQLite Data Base in Android upon inserting?
I am using unique keys on 3 rows (id, isbn, google_id) and I simply always add and ignore conflict. What are the ways to get conflicts upon inserting in entry already exists. Should I query before or I can get like "some kind of trace back" so that I will be able to notify user that entry already exists?

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();      
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(KEY_TITLE, book.getTitle());
 values.put ...

long id = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_BOOKS,
          null,
          values,
          SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);


 db.close();
```

Comment: for now I use instead of db.insertWithOnConflict db.insertOrThrow. But I cant get specific error type or can I?

Answer (score 1):

`CONFLICT_IGNORE` means that you want to ignore conflicts.

If that is not what you want, you have to use a different function, such as `insertOrThrow()`.
However, even if you get an exception, it is almost impossible to get information about the specific row that triggered the conflict, or if the error was even caused by such a conflict, or by something else.

If you want to identify the duplicate row, you have to query the database for it before you try to insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these method to check if your data already exist in your dataBase,Like the code below :

```
   public boolean rowIdExists(String username,int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from " + TABLE_NAME
            + " where userID=? AND id=?", new String[]{"" + username,""+id});
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    Log.i("UserExist",""+exists);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
```

the when you check your data :

```
 if (rowIdExists(username,id))
 {
   Notify the user that data already exist 
 }
else 
{
  Insert your data 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

android SQL is really hard to debug, 
you can always take the SQL table file and open it at any SQL viewer.
that would be your best bet

Most people just use open source library's for SQL in android, like active android for example.

for more information click the flowing link:

http://www.activeandroid.com/